# Use document root instead of virtual document root for $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

Tags: php, apache

I've set up a couple of sites with apache2.4 and define a VirtualDocumentRoot for every site. Basically they all point to different folders.

PHP's $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] points to whatever is set in VirtualDocumentRoot as opposed to DocumentRoot. How do I set it up so that PHP takes the original document root and not the VirtualDocumentRoot?

Comment: I don't think you can. The document root is essentially the root of the (virtual) domain. It's working the way it's supposed to work. But I think you can work something out with [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

OK so what I did was this:

Use VirtualDocumentRoot anyway, but manually change the documentroot to what I wanted it to be with this method:

In the apache site vhost config I added this:

```
php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/html/setdocroot.php
```

Setdocroot.php:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "/var/www/html";
```

That way the files are still served from the VirtualDocumentRoot specified, but PHP's $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] still uses the DocumentRoot path.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.